# Django Reusing models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have Django application with 30+ models. I want to write an application that can take a snapshot of the data in some of the models. I want to write the models once and reuse them in each application so that if I maintain it in one place, the only difference being that when I call `python manage.py syncdb` the same table are created with different table prefixes.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This is how Django is designed - just put those models in an app and use it across multiple projects.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly where the reusable app principle comes into play.
([as explained at the django website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/reusable-apps/))

Comment: What I meant was that I want to reuse the same model classes in different apps with different prefixes